# MagicalRecord 3.0 Setup

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I have my xcdatamodel file in a static library so I can share it across projects. Using MagicalRecord 2.2 I could this to get the app to recognize my object model.

```
NSBundle *dataBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dataBundle]];

[MagicalRecord setShouldAutoCreateManagedObjectModel:NO];
[NSManagedObjectModel MR_setDefaultManagedObjectModel:objectModel];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"WhoAt.sqlite"];
```

MagicalRecord 3.0 changed that and I'm struggling to get it up and running. Using the default setup methods, I get entity not found when trying to save.  This is expected because the object model hasn't been merged.  When I try to merge it using the below code, there's an assertion failure that store (property on the `MagicalRecordStack` object) is null.

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/WADataModel.bundle", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
NSBundle *dataBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dataBundle]];

MagicalRecordStack *stack = [[AutoMigratingMagicalRecordStack alloc] initWithStoreNamed:@"WhoAt.sqlite"];
[stack setModel:objectModel];
[MagicalRecordStack setDefaultStack:stack];
```

I also tried setting the object model after using one of the setup methods, but that failed as well.  Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I stopped using 2.2 because it kept blocking the main thread for fetches and saves.  I was hoping 3.0 would fix this problem.

Comment: So, the fetching hasn't changed significantly. Background fetching is something we could add if a pull request is provided ...

Comment: Will it continue to block for saves?

Comment: Much of that api hasn't been significantly changed either. It will depend on the stack you use as to whether the save will block.

Comment: I changed the concurrency type of the main queue context to `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. Works great now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so are you sure you're loading a data model in your model loading code? Is objectModel not nil and contain entities you expect? The steps you're showing here seem correct. That is:

1. Identify the bundle where the model(s) are located
2. Load the bundle
3. Load the model from the bundle
4. Set the model on the stack prior to accessing the context (the context is lazy loaded, and thus triggers the model and all the other components to load)

If you log the stack object, what shows up? You should see if it loads the model, stores, etc from the log output.

Comment: I don't remember exactly where I was running into issues. Probably number 4.  I ended up creating a very simplified core data frame using MagicalRecord as an example.  It's a great framework, but too heavy for my needs (logging and key/value store).